# How to get a list of all eslint rules that errored during linting?

Tags: eslint, yarnpkg

I'm currently in the process of updating the eslint packages being used for a large codebase. After the update eslint is now finding errors on thousands of files that fail different rules.

Is there a way to run eslint and have it output a list of the rules that failed?

By default eslint runs through each file and outputs each line that failed. Instead I want to build a list of rules that failed (no duplicates) like below:

i.e.

```
no-console
react/no-multi-comp
react/jsx-curly-spacing
```

My intent is to turn all these failing rules off in the `eslint.js` file, but was hoping for an easy way to collate this list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an eslint formater to do this. Here are a couple that you might consider

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-formatter-summary
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-formatter-summary-chart

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to search `eslint` errors for unique rule names:

```bash
eslint . | grep error | grep -o '[-/0-9a-z]*$' | sort | uniq
```